# Delete old log files in AIX

Tags: unix, shell-script, find, aix, ksh

I am trying write a script to delete old log files in `\var\log\applog\nmon` on my AIX system. We usually get alerts that the file system is almost full and at the moment delete old files by hand. So basically what i am looking for is a script that I can schedule in a `cron` job . This script should keep logs for two months and delete the rest.

There are two files I don't want to be deleted: `.profile` and `.sh_history`.

I tried this command:

```
find nmon -mtime  +60 -type f -not -name ".profile" -not -name ".sh_history" –delete
```

It works fine but it also deletes those two file which I mentioned earlier .

I am not sure how to proceed with the script so that i can delete old logs file but not those two files.

I tried above command but it gave me this error:

```
find: 0652-017 -not is not a valid option.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) does not specify `-not`, so I guess `AIX find` does not implement it. You will want to use `!` to negate an expression, e.g.

```
! -name .sh_history
```